# EF Unidirectional foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, many-to-one

Provided I have two code-first entities:

User:

```
public class User 
{
    public User() {}

    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;} 
}
```

City:

```
public class City
{
    public City() {}
    [Key]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How do I make a Foreign key relationship so that the User table will have a `City_Name` FK, containing a string that has to correspond to one of the Names from the City table? I don't need the reference in the other direction, I just want to make sure that the `City_Name` in `dbo.Users` will be from the `Name` column in the `dbo.Cities`.

If I just make a migration with a model like that, it will create the `City_Name` column in `dbo.Users` and Inserting works fine, but if I want to return a `User` obj, the `City` is always `null`, even if I manually load the City with `dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.City).Load()`.

Any ideas or insights to what I might be doing wrong, and how is this kind of a relationship achieved in EF ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class User 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("CityMappedToUser")]
  public string City_Name {get; set;}

  public virtual City CityMappedToUser{get; set;} 
}
```

It's explained pretty good on msdn tbh: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Thank you , I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need something like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public User() {}

    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public string City_Name {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("City_Name")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public City() {}
    [Key]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```